# Are the setiosflags parameters the same as the standalone ones?

Tags: c++

I noticed that iomanip allows you to format output with possibilities such as `left` and `setioflags(ios::left)`. Likewise, there's `fixed` and `setiosflags(ios::fixed)`. Are these just two names for the same thing or is there any differences between the two commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, setiosflags is just a manipulator version of ios_base::setf. I bet in most if not all implementations it is simply calling ios_base::setf on the stream.

Non-parametrised manipulators, like std::left and std::fixed are doing the same thing, but are working with their individual flags.

Answer (score 0):

There's the function [`std::left`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left), which can be used as

```
cout << setw(80) << left << 4.13 << endl;
```

and there's the flag [`left`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/fmtflags), which can be used in [`setiosflags(ios::left)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setiosflags) or [`setf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/setf)

These are just different ways to accomplish the same formatting.